# Is there a way to print mailing labels from a report

Tags: civireport, address-labels

Currently, reports do not have a way to print mailing labels. Our specific requirement is to make use of the "Upcoming Birthdays Report" to print mailing labels for donors so we can post them birthday cards and even just send them an email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to print labels from the results generated by running the "Upcoming Birthdays Report" as follows:

1. First I created a group and named it "Upcoming Birthdays".
2. I then ran the Upcoming Birthdays Report".
3. Added the results of the report to the "Upcoming Birthdays" group.
4. Then went to Search->Find Contacts. Selected the "Upcoming Birthdays" group and clicked Search.
5. Then from the search results, selected all records, and selected "Mailing labels - print" from the actions drop down.

Answer (score 3):

A couple options:

- From the report you can export to CSV and use that as a data source for a merge outside of Civi.
- If you create a smart group with the same criteria as the report you can quickly search for those who meet the criteria and print mailing labels from the search results. You can also use this smart group as a recipient list in CiviMail if you want to go the email route.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your second option looks more like what we want. However, just to clarify...we would run the "Upcoming Birthdays Report", then save the list to a smart group. Then search for the smart group and generate the labels. Correct?

Comment: You need to create the smart group via search results. There are details here: 

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/smart-groups/